# PHPExcel - Sometimes when i download the excel file it is corrupted and other sometimes it works

Tags: php, phpexcel

Im trying to convert a html table to excel using PHPExcel. The thing is, sometimes i get an error ('Cannot open file cause its format/extension is corrupted' and other times it doesnt and it runs perfectly.
Usually i get the error on the first 3 times i try to create the file and at the fourth time it goes well.

Does anyone have an idea on why this happens? I thought about the amount of information i put on the table but to be honest i dont know.

```
<?php
session_start();


require_once '../classes/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

$servidorodbc=file('../public/odbc.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$dsn=$servidorodbc['0'];
$user=$servidorodbc['1'];
$pwd=$servidorodbc['2'];


if($pwd="''"){
    $pwd="";
}


$ano = addslashes( $_SESSION['anopr']);


$mes = addslashes( $_SESSION['mespr']);


$db = odbc_connect($dsn, $user, $pwd);
$query = odbc_exec($db, "Select 
Cliente,Nome_Cli,CCusto,Descricao,Codigo,Nome,Tipo,Provisoes,Pagamentos,Acrescimos,Liquidacoes,Saldo,Ac_Provisoes,Ac_Pagamento,Ac_Acrescimos,Ac_Liquidacoes,Ac_Saldo,Amor_Abertura,Amor_Utilizacao,Amor_Fecho,Amor_Saldo
from GP_Provisoes_Acum where Ano=".$ano." and Mes=".$mes."
union all
Select Cliente=0,Nome_Cli='',CCusto=0,Descricao='SOMATÓRIOS TOTAIS',Codigo=0,Nome='',Tipo='TOTAL',
SUM(Provisoes) as Provisoes, SUM(Pagamentos) as Pagamentos,SUM(Acrescimos) as Acrescimos, 
SUM(Liquidacoes) as Liquidacoes,SUM(Saldo) as Saldo, SUM(Ac_Provisoes) as Ac_Provisoes, 
SUM(Ac_Pagamento) as Ac_Pagamento, SUM(Ac_Acrescimos) as Ac_Acrescimos, SUM(Ac_Liquidacoes) as Ac_Liquidacoes, 
SUM(Ac_Saldo) as Ac_Saldo, Amor_Abertura=0,Amor_Utilizacao=0,Amor_Fecho=0,Amor_Saldo=0
from GP_Provisoes_Acum where Ano=".$ano." and Mes=".$mes
);



$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$rowCount = 1; 

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,'Cliente');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount,'Nome do Cliente');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,'Centro de Custo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount,'Descricao');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,'Codigo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount,'Nome');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount,'Tipo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount,'Provisoes');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount,'Pagamentos');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount,'Acrescimo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.$rowCount,'Liquidacoes');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount,'Saldo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$rowCount,'Ac_Provisoes');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N'.$rowCount,'Ac_Pagamento');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O'.$rowCount,'Ac_Acrescimo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P'.$rowCount,'Ac_Liquidacoes');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q'.$rowCount,'Ac_Saldo');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('R'.$rowCount,'Amor_Abertura');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S'.$rowCount,'Amor_Utilização');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('T'.$rowCount,'Amor_Fecho');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('U'.$rowCount,'Amor_Saldo');

while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)){ 
      $rowCount++;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount,$row['Cliente']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount,$row['Nome_Cli']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount,$row['CCusto']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount,$row['Descricao']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount,$row['Codigo']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount,$row['Nome']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount,$row['Tipo']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount,$row['Provisoes']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount,$row['Pagamentos']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount,$row['Acrescimos']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.$rowCount,$row['Liquidacoes']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount,$row['Saldo']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('M'.$rowCount,$row['Ac_Provisoes']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('N'.$rowCount,$row['Ac_Pagamento']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('O'.$rowCount,$row['Ac_Acrescimos']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('P'.$rowCount,$row['Ac_Liquidacoes']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('Q'.$rowCount,$row['Ac_Saldo']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('R'.$rowCount,$row['Amor_Abertura']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('S'.$rowCount,$row['Amor_Utilizacao']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('T'.$rowCount,$row['Amor_Fecho']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('U'.$rowCount,$row['Amor_Saldo']);
}

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Tabela_de_Previsoes.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');





?>
```

Comment: Just FYI, PHPExcel is deprecated and has been replaced with [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

If your database contains millions of information then it can surely slowdown the process.

Another reason can be about of cells you are creating in a  loop.

A bit more info about the code will give better overview of the situation.

Comment: i got this error when i open the file with notepad <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7340032 bytes) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\classes\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorage\CacheBase.php</b> on line <b>177</b><br />

Comment: this happens because any of your input field is exceeding the data limit 
you need to check your database once
increase the limit where it can happen and see if the problem exists

Answer (score 0):

Corrupted excel file can be in that case, when there was an error during file generation.

Try to open an excel file with native text reader, such as notepad and see, is there any error/warning/notice.

Make sure to enable errors reporting/displaying.

Comment: yeah, i got this error  <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7340032 bytes) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\organizar\classes\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\CachedObjectStorage\CacheBase.php</b> on line <b>177</b><br />

Comment: It depends on which data you are putting in that excel, different data - different behaviour.

Comment: but i mean, if i try to put the same data on the excel it will work on the 4th / 5th try

Comment: like now, it didnt open the file for the first 4 times and at the fifth one it went well lol

Comment: try to increase the memory from 128M to 512M.